# Specific Caching Scenario for Web Application

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, caching

I am making a web application that involves being able to grab specific computer logs from multiple department stores. The application is getting data from a SQL Server DB. At the start of the app I ask the user to select a region number to narrow down their choices. After the region selection is made I make a call to the DB to retrieve the different stores in that area (I have made a Store class so I can create objects easily). I display them to the user so they can make their choice of which store they want. After the user chooses their store, I have to call the DB again to retrieve a list of workstations that belong to that store (again I have a class defined called Workstation). Then the user can select a workstation, pick a day and month they want a log from and hit a submit button.

When it comes to caching results from the DB I am confused on how to do this. Ideally I'd be caching Store and Workstation objects with some cache manager like JCS or EHCACHE. My first SQL statement to get the stores has a WHERE clause checking the REGION the user selected. So, As I get these results back in a ResultSet object do I iterate through them one by one and check if they're already in the cache? If they aren't in there then create a Store object and add it. If the object is already in cache then use a continue statement to skip to the next iteration of the ResultSet?

And do you think it would even be wise to consider caching log info that was asked for on a certain day and month if it's in the past?

I'm looking for some guidance on how to continue this project and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out or give me a general walk through or recommendation on how to proceed. The programming itself is not the problem. It's just my unfamiliarity with caching itself.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then the user can select a workstation, pick a day and month they want a log from and hit a submit button.

Based on this statement, I am assuming that the log for a particular day and month will not be updated once it has been written to the database.

> So, As I get these results back in a ResultSet object do I iterate through them one by one and check if they're already in the cache?

It looks like using Hibernate with a second level cache and query caching would be a better option for you instead of using just a cache. Since your question is a high level question, I am not going to get into the details of what is Hibernate and how to us Hibernate and configure a second level cache and a query cache.

See [this](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html) for more details on query cache. The article is a bit old but it did help me understand the basics of query caching.

> And do you think it would even be wise to consider caching log info that was asked for on a certain day and month if it's in the past?

I don't think there is anything wrong in caching past data. The primary purpose of caching data is to make data required by your application available quickly when it is required. If accessing this data requires you to hit the database or read from a file everytime the data is required, a cache makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. As it stands now the actual workstation logs are on the given workstation itself and not in any kind of database. Once the user hits submit I rely on the "net use" DOS command to actually grab the log, copy it, zip and FTP it to a vendor.

Comment: What the link said about using Hibernate makes sense and sounds like a good solution. I also found this handy link:http://mastertheboss.com/quickstart-tutorials-hibernate/jpa/hibernate-tutorial-with-eclipse

Comment: Then it looks like your database won't be updated that frequently unless workstations are going to be moved from one store to another every hour :). I have edited my answer to clarify more of your doubts. Good to hear that Hibernate can work for you. Don't forget to tick this answer as accepted if you decide to go with Hibernate.

Comment: Another question I have about enterprise web app caching deals with the amount of people using the application. If at any given time 2 people are using the application and let's say one person wants logs from workstation #8 at store A and the other wants logs from workstation #1 at the same store A. After the first person's request for that store and workstations are cached, is this second person's request data (as far as the store and workstation go) coming from that saved cache data? Hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: Are we talking about a distributed cache? If not, then it doesn't matter which user is making the request. What matters is the query and the query parameters. I suggest you write a sample app and observe the Hibernate query logs to see when does Hibernate actually hit the database and when does it fetch data from the cache. You need to turn on query logging in Hibernate for this.

Comment: Thank you again for your advice. I think I'll go with hibernate and delve into further.