# Web Application Database Mem-Cache Suggestions

Tags: java, database, memcached

My website serve live info to user. These information can change dynamically. (You can think it is a STOCK Prices) My each query time to get these information from db about 3-5 seconds. My total time to get all information about 3 minutes. I serve these information to 6000 user. I am using hashmap to store and serve information to users. I get all information from db every 5 minutes and store it on hashmap. Everything is OK but I want to use advanced cache systems. What is your suggest. Can I use HSQLDB for that? INFO: I am using Spring MVC + Hibernate so I don't want to use non-JAVA solutions such as REDIS.

Comment: Since you are already using Hibernate, why not look into second level caching? I am not completely clear about what your application does but you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846718/specific-caching-scenario-for-web-application/23847243#23847243

Comment: These info is critical for my users. Can I guarantee cache will be change in 5 minutes interval and users reach info everytime under seconds with second level caching.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ehcache as a second level cache for hibernate or as "self managed" cache. Guava library offers also efficient cache capibilities.